# How to get entire snapshot of scrollview/tableview(Autolayout/SnapKit)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, scrollview, snapkit

When I use Frame to layout subviews, I could get entire snapshot of scrollview. But when I use AutoLayout/SnapKit, the code below will not work. Why?

```
extension UIScrollView {

    var cc_snapshot: UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0)
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        let previousFrame = frame
        let previousOffset = contentOffset
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
        contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        layer.render(in: context)
        frame = previousFrame
        contentOffset = previousOffset
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

}
```

Comment: probably because snapkit is trash and you don't have a frame set when you try to snapshot it. snapkit literally makes your job more difficult than had you just used layout constraints raw. it's not hard.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So what did you try?